# NSFetchedResultsController swift sections

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table view that takes data from a CoreData entity with 3 fields. firstName: String, lastName: String and done:NSNumber (which is a UISwitch that can be turned ON or OFF).

I want to populate the table with the first and last names but first section is with names having the Switch ON, and a second section with names having the Switch OFF.

here is the code that saves the data:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
var newItem: List? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var txtFirst: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtLast: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var switchDone: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissVC()
}
@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let context = self.context
    let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: context)

    let nItem = List(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    nItem.firstName = txtFirst.text
    nItem.lastName = txtLast.text
    nItem.done = switchDone.on
    context.save(nil)        
    dismissVC()
}
func dismissVC() {
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
}
```

and here is the code that populates the table view:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}
func listFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    frc = getFetchedResultsController()
    frc.delegate = self
    frc.performFetch(nil)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
    return numberOfSections!
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberOfRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    return numberOfRowsInSection!
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let list = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List

    cell.textLabel?.text = list.firstName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = list.lastName

    return cell
}

}
```

I just can't figure out how to separate the data into the two sections based on the 'done' attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to sort your `List` objects by the `done` attribute, then the `firstName`:

```
let doneSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "done", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [doneSortDescriptor, sortDescriptor]
```

Then amend your Fetched Results Controller to get it to use the `done` attribute to define the sections:

```
frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "done", cacheName: nil)
```

Finally, implement `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection` to set an appropriate title for each section.