# Trying to convert to NSFetchedResultsController "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to convert a working table view to a table view making use of NSFetchedResultsController.

I am testing with just two entries and this is part of my working code

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Appointments")
        //3
        do {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            invoices = results as Array<AnyObject>  //cast to Appointments didn't work           
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

And this is part of my converting code

```
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

func getFetchedResultsController()->NSFetchedResultsController {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}

func listFetchRequest()->NSFetchRequest{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Appointments")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "appointmentUser", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}

var appointments = [AnyObject]()//[NSManagedObject]()
```

It builds successfull, but i am directly getting an error message:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ():
0x1002c0a50 <+0>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
0x1002c0a54 <+4>:   mov    x29, sp
0x1002c0a58 <+8>:   sub    sp, sp, #16
0x1002c0a5c <+12>:  and    w8, w2, #0x1
0x1002c0a60 <+16>:  tbnz   w8, #0, 0x1002c0a80       ; <+48>
0x1002c0a64 <+20>:  tbnz   x1, #63, 0x1002c0ac4      ; <+116>
0x1002c0a68 <+24>:  add    x1, x0, x1
0x1002c0a6c <+28>:  mov    x2, x3
0x1002c0a70 <+32>:  mov    x3, x4
    0x1002c0a74 <+36>:  mov    x4, x5
    0x1002c0a78 <+40>:  bl     0x10030d910               ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
->  0x1002c0a7c <+44>:  brk    #0x1
    0x1002c0a80 <+48>:  str    xzr, [sp, #8]
    0x1002c0a84 <+52>:  cmp    x0, w0, uxtw
```

How can i check where the unwrapping occurs? How can i fix this?

[EDIT]
With some trial and error (outcommenting parts) i think it has to do with this part of my code

```
        override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
//        return 1
        let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
        return numberOfSections!
    }
```

see also: [NSFetchedResultsController swift sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946986/nsfetchedresultscontroller-swift-sections)

Comment: Why do you declare `invoices` as `[AnyObject]` although it's doubtless `[NSManagedObject]`. The more specific the code is designed the less compiler errors/warnings and even crashes you get. -- `invoices = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]`. If any error occurs it will be caught properly.

Comment: if i am casting to Appointments i am getting fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Comment: Ok i had to add class id in model file as well see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304638/fetchrequest-nsarray-element-failed-to-match-the-swift-array-element-type-sw
but still frc is not working as expected

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this piece of code:

```
// issue 1
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

// issue 2
func getFetchedResultsController()->NSFetchedResultsController {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}
```

Issue 1: `NSFetchedResultsController` is being instantiated (but not configured) and stored in `frc`.

Issue 2: The function creates a new, configured, `NSFetchedResultsController` (and stores it in `frc`) every time it is called.

I think what you were trying to achieve here is lazy instantiation, remove the `getFetchedResultsController` function and replace the variable declaration with this:

```
lazy var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: self.listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: self.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

This will setup the fetched results controller when the `frc` property is first accessed and assign the delegate as `self`.

Based on your comments the `viewDidLoad` method will look something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do {
        try self.frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, i  am getting an error message "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call" when i use your lazy instantiation

Comment: @alex I've updated my answer, it needs to reference `self`

Comment: your new function does built but didn't fix my problem. I had to replace this code ` frc = getFetchedResultsController()
        frc.delegate = self
        do {
            try  frc.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }` to viewDidLoad . I had the code in viewDidAppear

Comment: @alex You don't need the `getFetchedResultsController` function, I'll update my answer again...